# How can I draw a plot for getting probability of binary outcome

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization

My data has the following structure and it has 50 000 simples in wich  duration is ranged between 2 secondes and 10 day

```
  Id        duration          y
   1             23           0
   2             64           1
   3             15           1
```

I would like to draw a plot that can visualize the vriation of duration and the probability to get outcome positive.

I need to work with python this problem

Comment: Is duration on a discrete or continuous scale?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Yes duhaime  the duration is continuous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is a histgram of duration and a probability distribution of y.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

duration=[23,64,15,18,1,63,21,27]
y=[0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1]
BUCKET_SIZE=10

numToBucket=lambda x: round(math.ceil(x/BUCKET_SIZE))

yCount=[0]*numToBucket(max(duration))
hist=[0]*numToBucket(max(duration))

for i in range(len(duration)):
    index=numToBucket(duration[i])-1
    hist[index]+=1
    yCount[index]+=y[i]

probDist=[0 if (yCount[i]==0) else yCount[i]/hist[i] for i in range(len(hist))]

axis=[i*BUCKET_SIZE for i in range(len(hist))]

print(hist)
print(yCount)
print(probDist)

plt.bar(axis, hist, align='center', alpha=0.5)
plt.title('Histogram')

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks it works correctly but you need to add probDist=[] and plt.bar(axis, probDist...)